# Is there a way for me to safely install PowerShell 4 on SBS 2011?

Tags: windows-sbs-2011, winrm, powershell-v4.0

## I want PS4 on SBS2011

A requirement of a software our office uses is PowerShell 4.  The server is Windows Small Business Server 2011.

## But PS4 and SBS2011 seem incompatible

According to the TechNet Wiki entry [*How to Install Windows PowerShell 4.0*](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/21016.how-to-install-windows-powershell-4-0.aspx) there are *Known issues* with WMF4.0 on SBS 2011.  And in [the release notes linked on the wiki](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40855), under *System Requirements* they state:

> **Supported Operating System**
>
> Windows 7, Windows Embedded Standard 7, Windows Server 2008 R2, Windows Server 2012
>
> **IMPORTANT** - Systems that are running the following server applications should not run Windows Management Framework 4.0 at this
>   time.
>
> - System Center 2012 Configuration Manager (not including SP1)
> - System Center Virtual Machine Manager 2008 R2 (including SP1)
> - Microsoft Exchange Server 2007
> - Windows Small Business Server 2011 Standard

## What now?

So where does that leave me?
Is there a way to just update PowerShell from v2 to v4 without installing the whole WMF4.0?